# RVIZ2 and RTAB-map are not communicating

Tags: ros2, rviz

So I want to capture a 3d map for my VSLAM project on my Jetson Orin Nano (using Jetpack 6) utilizing the Intel RealSense D435i depth camera. So far, I have downloaded ROS2 Humble and RTAB-map, and I successfully managed to capture a 3d point cloud of the room using RTAB-map. However, to visualize the map, I see the integrated visualzer for RTAB-map really buggy, so after some research I found out that RVIZ2 is good way to visualize the map generated in RTAB-map (correct me I am wrong).... So after more research on how to make RVIZ display the RTAB-map, I found out that both applications should be running simultaneously. And to setup RVIZ2 I need to "add" a display , choose point cloud2 and set the topic as /rtabmap/point_cloud (I can only type in the topic the dropdown menu isn't showing anything). However, the map isn't displaying... I also tested if at least it can detect the camera, but that isn't working either.

**I am still learning about ROS so please correct any shortcomings I mentioned above.**

The picture below shows both applications running simultaneously:

[image]

If you see anything wrong with my RVIZ setup please tell me:

And the second picture contains the terminals RTAB-map and RVIZ2 and the ROS topic list for you reference:

[image]

Your help is much appreciated!